# Conditionally format cell color based one 2 values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet, the screenshot, I want to color cell E (green), if the text contains "keto" **AND** "250g". Both of these values not just one. At the moment I don't know how to do it for 2 strings, only for 1. This is the code used for 1 string:

```
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules(); 
conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp
    .newConditionalFormatRule() 
    .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('E1:E10000')]) 
    .whenTextContains("Brownies") 
    .setBackground('#B7E1CD') 
    .build());
```

[image]

Comment: Ask only 1 question per post. See [ask] and [mcve]. Try something like [````.whenFormulaSatisfied(`=QUERY(E1, " select '1'  where E contains 'keto'  and E contains '250g'  label '1' ''")`)````](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#whenFormulaSatisfied(String))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use `.whenFormulaSatisfied`

Credit to @TheMaster for suggesting that in the comments.

I had to reorder your code since it did not work. It seemed you were calling variables before they were defined, and setting the rules for the sheet, before you had built them.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()
  var conditionalFormatRules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp
    .newConditionalFormatRule() 
    .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('E1:E10')])

    // HERE IS THE RELEVANT METHOD
    .whenFormulaSatisfied('=AND( FIND("Keto",E1) , FIND("250g",E1) )')

    .setBackground('#B7E1CD') 
    .build());
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules)
}
```

#### References and Explanation

The documentation for [`whenFormulaSatisfied`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#whenformulasatisfiedformula).

I used the [AND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301) formula along with the [FIND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126) formula to get it to return `TRUE` only if the cell contains both.

You probably made a mistake while copying and pasting, but please be careful to `getConditionalFormatRules` and `build()` *before* calling `setConditionalFormatRules`.

#### An alternative method for doing similar things

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but here it is just in case. You could explore the [`onEdit(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger. Every time an edit is made to the sheet by a user, it will run. The `e` parameter that you use contains the details of the edit, such as the range. From there you can create an if statement that checks if it contains the strings you want it to. It allows you to separate out the logic of checking from the logic of formatting. If you need more complex behavior out of your sheet, then conditional formatting will start to get tedious quickly.

Here is some reference material on triggers:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) - for the most basic triggers.
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) - if you need your trigger to have more functionality.

Comment: Thank you so much for this @iansedano. I am not very familiar with google scripts, hence the code that is halfway. There is already a conditionaformatrules in the script.  
`var conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('D1:D10000')])
  .whenCellNotEmpty()
  .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
  .build());/ `

The rest of the script has pretty much the same code for different text (like the one in my question). How do I add yours to the end of this

Comment: Glad to help, but this follow up question starts to seem to be a bit of a different topic to the original question, and so might be **out of scope**, in theory you should try work with the solution and ask another question if needed. Though in your case it should be as simple as copying my code from `conditionalFormatRules.push...` to `.build())` and putting it on the line after `.build())` in your script. Yet **before** `setConditionalFormatRules`! Good documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder).